# Cannot launch Android virtual device after power cut

Tags: android, sdk, adb

I have the latest SDK running on Win7 and had set up some AVDs. However, there was a power cut a few days ago and since then, no avd will launch for me. From the Eclipse IDE there is no indication in the console output that the AVD is being run. If I run the AVD manager and try to launch from there, I get a progress bar with the title 'Starting Emulator for AVD 'MyAVD'.

To try to resolve this i removed all AVDs, uninstalled the entire SDK and re-installed but the issue persists. To add to this, when i run adb get-state I get the return value of 'unknown'.

This is driving me a little nuts, any help would be appreciated! I'd rather not go down the route of a system wipe.

Comment: Uhmmmm.... whats a power cut got to do with not launching AVD's? Easier to blame external factors then something else... what did you do?

Comment: Because when the power went off, the machine went off too. Simple fact is, the emulator was working before it. Since then, it hasn't worked. Clearly there's something that's been messed up by the machine going off when the power went but I don't know enough about the AVD setup to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Seems that the issue is with the emulator-arm and emulator-x86 apps. Looks like they are trying to do something with the graphics and there's a DLL missing

Faulting application name: emulator-x86.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4fe779fb
Faulting module name: atioglxx.dll, version: 6.14.10.9236, time stamp: 0x4b2aaf58
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000b212
Faulting process id: 0x1620
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd5c66f9e3498c

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the power failure did some damage to the registry and/or video driver files. Removed the drivers, ran a registry too to remove all references and then re-installed the ATI drivers. Emulator now working fine.